# Using Reflection to analyze Parameters and their values

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I've seen older posts here on SO, about one year old which would mean that they do not really cover .NET 4 or maybe even 3.5 on this topic. So here goes.

If you with reflection were to fetch parameters for the current method

```
ParameterInfo[] methodParams = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
```

Looping through each parameter will let you fetch the parameter-name however, there is only a "DefaultValue" which I guess is there because of the new Dynamic Parameters in .NET 4.

However, my question is; Is it still not possible to get the method parameter values without digging into the debugger API?

I know that there might be a design flaw if you even need to consider using this.

Comment: I think, I answered a very similar question not so long ago:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062883/is-there-a-way-to-enumerate-passed-method-paramters/2066654#2066654 As you said, not without design flaws, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get the current parameter values without using the Profiling API.

`MethodInfo` objects are per-method, not per-call.  There is no way to connect a `MethodInfo` with a given stack frame.

In addition, in Release builds, the parameter locals can be optimized out, so the values to not necessarily *exist*.

The `DefaultValue` property can be non-`null` in VB parameters, which already supports default values.

Comment: Is there a huge performance loss in doing that? Do you need to compile the project for debugging?

Comment: Using the Profiling API to get the value and not compiling in release-mode. It feels like it's not worth it.

Comment: Correct, especially because an application can't profile itself, so you'd need two EXE files.