# General way to get method parameters values from inside the method

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a lot of methods with variuos parameters:

```
method1(int a, byte b, string c){ ... }  
method2(object d, DateTime f){ ... }  
...
methodN(short g, short h, string i, object j){ ... }
```

The numbers and types of parameters are different everywhere but inside all those methods I have to enumerate them all as `[param name]:[value]`. Don't ask me why :)
Is there a way do to it without putting them together explicitly one by one? Is there something like method context that I can ask what parameters have come to the current method?

Comment: No, this isn't Javascript. There is no `arguments` array.

Comment: With C#6: `string paramValue = $"{nameof(a)}:{a}";`. If you want to enumerate all parameter there is only reflection. But i wouldn't use it without a really good reason

Comment: Also similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147368/using-reflection-to-analyze-parameters-and-their-values

Comment: The dup Q&A has an answer which can really assist you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717320/411632 (AOP)

Comment: crap yes! Thank you all guys, helped a lot!

Comment: I saw AOP mentioned in duplicates, but didn't see concrete implementation (PostSharp) is mentioned there. With PostSharp (free version) you can do that easily.

Comment: Nowadays a feature that could be used to achieve this is [Roslyn's Source Generators](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/source-generators.md). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717291/get-methods-parameters-names-and-values-from-inside-method/63277169#63277169)