# Convert method parameters into array

Tags: vb.net

Is there a Visual Basic.NET method that can convert method parameters into an array?

For instance instead of:

```
Function functionName(param1 as object, param2 as object) as object
ArrayName = {param1, param2}
```

you could do something like:

```
Function functionName(param1 as object, param2 as object) as object
ArrayName = MethodThatGetsAllFunctionParams
```

Just curious really.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There's not really enough detail in your question for me to tell. What does it mean to convert them into an array?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288597/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-array-of-the-arguments-passed-to-a-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of doing that. The language itself doesn’t allow that. You can use reflection to get the currently executing method of the [`StackFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod.aspx) of the execution. But even then [it’s still impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076/obtain-parameter-values-from-stackframe-in-net/75289#75289) to retrieve the parameter values.

The only solution is to “patch” the applications by introducing point cuts into the method call. The linked answer mentions a possibility for that.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at ParamArrays.  I think this solves what you're asking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

EDIT:

You could initialise a custom collection using your current function signature

```
Public Class CustomCollection(Of T)
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)

    Sub New(param1 As T, param2 As T)
        MyBase.New()
        MyBase.Add(param1)
        MyBase.Add(param2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and then call the function using

```
Dim result = functionName(New CustomCollection(Of Object)(param1, param2))
```

The Function signature would be changed to:

```
Public Function functionName(ByVal args As CustomCollection(Of Object)) As String
```

Comment: No, I don't want to send an unspecified number of arguments to a method.

Comment: Note, you can remove the generics from the above and change it all to Object if you prefer.  Just gives you some options on Overloading.